# Excel view data based upon drop down selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to view data from another sheet based upon selection from a dropdown.

I get an output file which I can't edit.
This is the basic output form

| Parts | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Part 1 | Name 1 | 06-xxxxxxxx |
| Part 1 | Name 2 | 06-xxxxxxxx |
| Part 1 | Name 3 | 06-xxxxxxxx |
| Part 2 | Name 4 | 06-xxxxxxxx |
| Part 2 | Name 5 | 06-xxxxxxxx |
| Part 3 | Name 6 | 06-xxxxxxxx |

The dropdown contains three options:"Part 1", "Part 2" and "Part 3"

If I select "Part 1" I want to output all rows containing "Part 1"

I hope to do this in a formula instead of an VBA script.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `FILTER()` formula should work. Try-

```
=FILTER(A:C,A:A=G1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an older version of excel and cannot use `Filter()` as Harun24hr suggested then you can add a Row Counter column.

```
=IF(A2=$G$1,1+SUM(D1:D1),"")
```

which can then be referenced using

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$C,MATCH(ROW(F1),$D:$D,0),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

where you want the output to be.
[image: excel cell examples]

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this](https://trumpexcel.com/extract-data-from-drop-down-list/) online and it worked like a charm...